# Number of possible products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have set (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), how many possible products are there of any three numbers from the set. Repeats are allowed e.g. 2*2*2, 2*3*3, etc.
I don't know how to solve this other than brute force. Thx a lot.

Comment: Are $2*4*9$ and $3*3*8$ considered to be the same product?

Comment: Yes, that is why you can't just do 8^3

Comment: Ok, so repetitions are not allowed?

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I am looking for the possible number of different products of any three numbers in the set. Ex. 2*4*4 and 2*2*8 count as one possible product.

Comment: I am confused. Your example seems to suggest we could use a number more than once, so that repetitions would indeed be allowed.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your comment. You can repeat a number but not a final product

Comment: I would probably do this with a computer. Is this part of an assignment where you are required to work by hand?

Comment: Maybe we can try to break down each number via prime factorisation. Now since we traditionally order the prime factorisation from smallest prime to largest prime we can get a unique representation, in this way it may be "easier" to tell where you'll get a redundancy or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The number of products consisting of $3$ elements with repetition from the $8$ element set 
>   \begin{align*}
> \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}=\{2,2^2,2^3,2\cdot 3, 3,3^2,5,7\}
> \end{align*}
>   is
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{8+3-1}{3}=\binom{10}{3}=\color{blue}{120}
> \end{align*}

Here the strategy is to count  the products which  occur more than once manually and then subtract this number from $120$.

- We can see at a glance  that  products having *two* elements from $\{5,7\}$ cannot have two different representations. Therefore candidates have either a factor $5$ or $7$ or none of them.

We need some kind of systematic way to find all possible products with multiple representations. In order to do so we arrange all candidates  according  to  two  criterias:

- The product contains either a  factor $5$ or  $7$ or none  of them
- We sort candidates by increasing  powers of  $2$

> **Products containing  $5$ or $7$:**
>
> We only need to list two factors, since the third one is either $5$ or $7$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{factor }2\ :&\qquad 2\cdot 3^2=(2\cdot 3)\cdot 3&(90,126)\\
> \text{factor }2^2:&\qquad  2^2\cdot3=2\cdot(2\cdot 3)&(60,84)\\
> &\qquad 2^2\cdot  3^2=(2\cdot  3)(2\cdot 3)&(180,252)\\
> \text{factor }2^3:&\qquad  2^3\cdot 3=2^2\cdot (2\cdot 3)&(120, 168)\\
> \text{factor }2^4:&\qquad 2\cdot 2^3=2^2\cdot 2^2&(80,112)\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We see there are $5$ possibilities  to  write   a product  with two different representations. Since the third factor is either $5$ or  $7$ we have a total of $\color{blue}{10}$  possibilities. The bracketed values on the right of each line give the number with factor  $5$ resp. $7$.
>
> **Products containing neither $5$ nor $7$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \text{factor }2\ :&\qquad   2\cdot  3\cdot  3^2=(2\cdot 3)\cdot 3\cdot 3=54\\
> &\qquad 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 3^2=(2\cdot 3)\cdot   3\cdot 3^2=162\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 2\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor  }2^2:&\qquad 2\cdot 2\cdot 3^2=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 3=2\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot 3=36\\
> &\qquad 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 3^2=2\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot 3^2=(2\cdot 3)(2\cdot 3)\cdot 3=108\\
> &\qquad 2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 3^2=(2\cdot 3)(2\cdot 3)\cdot 3^2=324\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 5\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor  }2^3:&\qquad 2\cdot 2^2\cdot 3=2\cdot 2\cdot (2\cdot 3)=24\\
> &\qquad 2\cdot 2^2 \cdot  3^2=2^2\cdot(2\cdot3)\cdot      3=2^3\cdot 3\cdot  3=2\cdot(2\cdot3)(2\cdot 3)=72\\
> &\qquad 2^3\cdot 3\cdot   3^2=2^2\cdot (2\cdot  3)\cdot 3^2=(2\cdot  3)(2\cdot 3)(2\cdot 3)=216\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 6\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor }2^4:&\qquad 2\cdot2^3\cdot    3=2^2\cdot2^2\cdot    3=2\cdot 2^2\cdot (2\cdot 3)=48\\
> &\qquad 2\cdot 2^3\cdot  3^2=2^2\cdot2^2\cdot   3^2=2^3\cdot(2\cdot3)\cdot3=2^2\cdot   (2\cdot      3)(2\cdot  3)=144\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 5\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor  }2^5:&\qquad   2\cdot 2\cdot2^3=2\cdot2^2\cdot2^2=32\\
> &\qquad   2^2\cdot   2^3\cdot 3=2\cdot  2^3\cdot (2\cdot  3)=2^2\cdot   2^2\cdot   (2\cdot  3)=96\\
> &\qquad       2^2\cdot  2^3\cdot 3^2=2^3\cdot   (2\cdot    3)(2\cdot   3)=288\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 4\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor }2^6:&\qquad     2\cdot  2^2\cdot 2^3=2^2\cdot    2^2\cdot 2^2=64\\
> &\qquad 2^3\cdot 2^3\cdot 3=2^2\cdot  2^3\cdot (2\cdot 3)=192\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 2\text{  multiples}\\
> \text{factor }2^7:&\qquad 2\cdot 2^3\cdot 2^3=2^2\cdot 2^2\cdot 2^3=128\\
> &\qquad \rightarrow 1\text{  multiple}\\
> \end{align*}
>   giving a total of $2+5+6+5+4+2+1=\color{blue}{25}$ multiple product representations.
>
> We conclude the number of different products is $$120-10-25=\color{blue}{85}.$$

Answer (score 1):

*This contsins some mistake.  Be careful

I try writing about my trying, but you may think that is  brute force. And it may have some mistake.
we should think the form of $2^a3^b5^c7^d(0\le a\le9,0\le b\le6,0\le c\le 3,0\le d\le3)$.

when $c=1,d=1$, then we can choose a number from$\{2,3,4,6,8,9\}$, so we get 6 numbers.

And think the case that $c=1,d\neq1$. If $4\le a\le6$,we can get only $(a,b)=(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(4,1)$(for example,$2\times8\times5,4\times8\times5,8\times8\times5,6\times8\times5$) because 8 or double $4$ is necessasry to make $a$ not less than $4$.If $3\le b\le4$, also we get $(a,b)=(0,3),(0,4),(1,3)$.

And in the case that $0\le a \le 3$ and $0\le b \le 2$, other than $(a,b)=(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$, we can get such a product(plese think a bit). So, we can know the number in the case equles to $4\times3-3=9$.
So, we now know the number in the case that $c=1,d\neq1$ equals to $9+4+3=16$, and the number in the case that $c\neq1,d=1$. It is equal. So, we can know the number in the case that $c=1$ or $d=1$. That is  $16\times 2+6=38$

Let's think about the case that $c=0$ and $d=1$. The form is $2^a3^b(a\le a\le 9,0\le b\le6)$.
if $7\le a\le9$, we get only $(a,b)=(7,0),(7,1),(8,0),(9,0)$, and if $5\le b \le6$, we get only $(a,b)=(0,5),(1,5),(0,6)$.

When $0\le a\le6$ and $0\le b\le4$, then that is a little difficult.
we can choose three number,so we know $a+b\ge3$ And, except $8$, each number has only two or one prime factor. So, we can think that

\begin{equation}3\le a+b\le8(a=6)\\3\le a+b\le7(3\le a\le5)\\3\le a+b\le6(0\le a\le2) \end{equation}
and if we think in the case classification on the value of $a$, we know the full pairs of $a,b$ which meet the former equation can be gotten. The number is $3+3+4+5+4+4+4=27$, so we know the number in case that $c=0$ and $d=1$ is $27+4+3=34$. Then, we know the answer is $34+38=72$

former answer:"
Because of [counting multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_coefficient), the number is less than $\binom {10}{3}=120$. But I can't get an accurate number. Sorry"

Comment: The answer from a brute force computation is 85.  I think most of the discrepancy is because you haven't included the cases where $5$ or $7$ is repeated.

Comment: thank you for your comnent. I will try to   amend it.